# Trying to figure out how to pass the function so then it can display the values

Tags: python

```
# Main to run
def main():
    keyboardInput = int(input('Enter the price of the land: $')) # grab user input 
    calculate(keyboardInput) # function to calculate w/ kbInput parameter
    display(assessmentValue, realTax)  # display the values <- this one right here

# Calculate the assessment value and property tax.  Display afterwards
def calculate(keyboardInput):
    assesssmentValue = keyboardInput * 0.60     # 60% for property actual value
    realTax = (assesssmentValue * .64) / 100    # calculate the tax
    return assesssmentValue, realTax
    
# Display the prices
def display(assesssmentValue, realTax):
    print('The assessment value is : $', format(assesssmentValue, '.2f'))
    print('The property tax is: $', format(realTax, '.2f'))
    # ^ display the values

# Call the main to run
main()
```

Overall things I've done so far:

1. tried to make variables for them, but I am also trying to figure out also how to grab the returning values from calculate function, if that was doable.
2. delete and revise the code, it works the method I tried, but I want to learn on this portion with which im stuck with.
3. everything so far from what I've seen works besides the option to display the function for additional info and context

Issue: display the "display" function from the main method

ps. sorry for the bad formatting of my post, new to here
EDIT: fixed typo in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the value from the `calculate()` call to your variables, on the outside.

```
def main():
    keyboardInput = int(input('Enter the price of the land: $'))
    assesssmentValue, realTax = calculate(keyboardInput) 
    display(assesssmentValue, realTax)
```